# For Autocomplete type text box Default Tab Navigaion not working for Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Normal Navigation of Tab button get stuck over autocomplete type text box in Mozilla Firefox browser. On Tab key press it's not moving to next element. Working fine in IE and Chrome. Can anyone assist me to fix this?

My Jquery Code is:

```
(function( $, undefined ) {

$.widget( "ui.autocomplete", {
    options: {
        appendTo: "body",
        delay: 300,
        minLength: 1,
        position: {
            my: "left top",
            at: "left bottom",
            collision: "none"
        },
        source: null
    },
    _create: function() {
        var self = this,
            doc = this.element[ 0 ].ownerDocument;
        this.element
            .addClass( "ui-autocomplete-input" )
            .attr( "autocomplete", "off" )
            // TODO verify these actually work as intended
            .attr({
                role: "textbox",
                "aria-autocomplete": "list",
                "aria-haspopup": "true"
            })
            .bind( "keydown.autocomplete", function( event ) {
                if ( self.options.disabled ) {
                    return;
                }

                var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode;
                switch( event.keyCode ) {
                case keyCode.PAGE_UP:
                    self._move( "previousPage", event );
                    break;
                case keyCode.PAGE_DOWN:
                    self._move( "nextPage", event );
                    break;
                case keyCode.UP:
                    self._move( "previous", event );
                    // prevent moving cursor to beginning of text field in some browsers
                    event.preventDefault();
                    break;
                case keyCode.DOWN:
                    self._move( "next", event );
                    // prevent moving cursor to end of text field in some browsers
                    event.preventDefault();
                    break;
                case keyCode.ENTER:
                case keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER:
                    // when menu is open or has focus
                    if ( self.menu.element.is( ":visible" ) ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                    //passthrough - ENTER and TAB both select the current element
                case keyCode.TAB:
                    if ( !self.menu.active ) {
                        return;
                    }
                    self.menu.select( event );
                    break;
                case keyCode.ESCAPE:
                    self.element.val( self.term );
                    self.close( event );
                    break;
                default:
                    // keypress is triggered before the input value is changed
                    clearTimeout( self.searching );
                    self.searching = setTimeout(function() {
                        // only search if the value has changed
                        if ( self.term != self.element.val() ) {
                            self.selectedItem = null;
                            self.search( null, event );
                        }
                    }, self.options.delay );
                    break;
                }
            })
            .bind( "focus.autocomplete", function() {
                if ( self.options.disabled ) {
                    return;
                }

                self.selectedItem = null;
                self.previous = self.element.val();
            })
            .bind( "blur.autocomplete", function( event ) {
                if ( self.options.disabled ) {
                    return;
                }

                clearTimeout( self.searching );
                // clicks on the menu (or a button to trigger a search) will cause a blur event
                self.closing = setTimeout(function() {
                    self.close( event );
                    self._change( event );
                }, 150 );
            });
        this._initSource();
        this.response = function() {
            return self._response.apply( self, arguments );
        };
//this.menu.element.hide();
            this.menu = $( "<ul></ul>" )
            .addClass( "ui-autocomplete" )
            .appendTo( $( this.options.appendTo || "body", doc )[0] )
            // prevent the close-on-blur in case of a "slow" click on the menu (long mousedown)
            .mousedown(function( event ) {
                // clicking on the scrollbar causes focus to shift to the body
                // but we can't detect a mouseup or a click immediately afterward
                // so we have to track the next mousedown and close the menu if
                // the user clicks somewhere outside of the autocomplete
                var menuElement = self.menu.element[ 0 ];
                if ( event.target === menuElement ) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $( document ).one( 'mousedown', function( event ) {
                            if ( event.target !== self.element[ 0 ] &&
                                event.target !== menuElement &&
                                !$.ui.contains( menuElement, event.target ) ) {
                                self.close();
                            }
                        });
                    }, 1 );
                }

                // use another timeout to make sure the blur-event-handler on the input was already triggered
                setTimeout(function() {
                    clearTimeout( self.closing );
                }, 13);
            })
            .menu({
                focus: function( event, ui ) {
                    var item = ui.item.data( "item.autocomplete" );
                    if ( false !== self._trigger( "focus", null, { item: item } ) ) {
                        // use value to match what will end up in the input, if it was a key event
                        if ( /^key/.test(event.originalEvent.type) ) {
                            self.element.val( item.value );
                        }
                    }
                },
                selected: function( event, ui ) {
                    var item = ui.item.data( "item.autocomplete" ),
                        previous = self.previous;

                    // only trigger when focus was lost (click on menu)
                    if ( self.element[0] !== doc.activeElement ) {
                        self.element.focus();
                        self.previous = previous;
                    }

                    if ( false !== self._trigger( "select", event, { item: item } ) ) {
                        self.element.val( item.value );
                    }

                    self.close( event );
                    self.selectedItem = item;
                },
                blur: function( event, ui ) {
                    // don't set the value of the text field if it's already correct
                    // this prevents moving the cursor unnecessarily
                    if ( self.menu.element.is(":visible") &&
                        ( self.element.val() !== self.term ) ) {
                        self.element.val( self.term );
                    }
                }
            })
            .zIndex( this.element.zIndex() + 1 )
            // workaround for jQuery bug #5781 http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5781
            .css({ top: 0, left: 0 })
            .hide()
            .data( "menu" );
        if ( $.fn.bgiframe ) {
             this.menu.element.bgiframe();
        }
    },

    destroy: function() {
        this.element
            .removeClass( "ui-autocomplete-input" )
            .removeAttr( "autocomplete" )
            .removeAttr( "role" )
            .removeAttr( "aria-autocomplete" )
            .removeAttr( "aria-haspopup" );
        this.menu.element.remove();
        $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
    },

    _setOption: function( key, value ) {
        $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply( this, arguments );
        if ( key === "source" ) {
            this._initSource();
        }
        if ( key === "appendTo" ) {
            this.menu.element.appendTo( $( value || "body", this.element[0].ownerDocument )[0] )
        }
    },

    _initSource: function() {
        var array,
            url;
        if ( $.isArray(this.options.source) ) {
            array = this.options.source;
            this.source = function( request, response ) {
                response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(array, request.term) );
            };
        } else if ( typeof this.options.source === "string" ) {
            url = this.options.source;
            this.source = function( request, response ) {
                $.getJSON( url, request, response );
            };
        } else {
            this.source = this.options.source;
        }
    },

    search: function( value, event ) {
        value = value != null ? value : this.element.val();
        if ( value.length < this.options.minLength ) {
            return this.close( event );
        }

        clearTimeout( this.closing );
        if ( this._trigger("search") === false ) {
            return;
        }

        return this._search( value );
    },

    _search: function( value ) {
        this.term = this.element
            .addClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" )
            // always save the actual value, not the one passed as an argument
            .val();

        this.source( { term: value }, this.response );
    },

    _response: function( content ) {
        if ( content.length ) {
            content = this._normalize( content );
            this._suggest( content );
            this._trigger( "open" );
        } else {
            this.close();
        }
        this.element.removeClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );
    },

    close: function( event ) {
        clearTimeout( this.closing );
        if ( this.menu.element.is(":visible") ) {
            this._trigger( "close", event );
            this.menu.deactivate();
        }
    },

    _change: function( event ) {
        if ( this.previous !== this.element.val() ) {
            this._trigger( "change", event, { item: this.selectedItem } );
        }
    },

    _normalize: function( items ) {
        // assume all items have the right format when the first item is complete
        if ( items.length && items[0].label && items[0].value ) {
            return items;
        }
        return $.map( items, function(item) {
            if ( typeof item === "string" ) {
                return {
                    label: item,
                    value: item
                };
            }
            return $.extend({
                label: item.label || item.value,
                value: item.value || item.label
            }, item );
        });
    },

    _suggest: function( items ) {
        var ul = this.menu.element
                .empty()
                .zIndex( this.element.zIndex() + 1 ),
            menuWidth,
            textWidth;
        this._renderMenu( ul, items );
        // TODO refresh should check if the active item is still in the dom, removing the need for a manual deactivate
        this.menu.deactivate();
        this.menu.refresh();
        this.menu.element.show().position( $.extend({
            of: this.element
        }, this.options.position ));

        menuWidth = ul.width( "" ).outerWidth();
        textWidth = this.element.outerWidth();
        ul.outerWidth( Math.max( menuWidth, textWidth ) );
    },

    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var self = this;
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            self._renderItem( ul, item );
        });
    },

    _renderItem: function( ul, item) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( $( "<a></a>" ).text( item.label ) )
            .appendTo( ul );
    },

    _move: function( direction, event ) {
        if ( !this.menu.element.is(":visible") ) {
            this.search( null, event );
            return;
        }
        if ( this.menu.first() && /^previous/.test(direction) ||
                this.menu.last() && /^next/.test(direction) ) {
            this.element.val( this.term );
            this.menu.deactivate();
            return;
        }
        this.menu[ direction ]( event );
    },

    widget: function() {
        return this.menu.element;
    }
});

$.extend( $.ui.autocomplete, {
    escapeRegex: function( value ) {
        return value.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
    },
    filter: function(array, term) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i" );
        return $.grep( array, function(value) {
            return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value );
        });
    }
});

}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: what happens if you comment out the `case keycode.TAB:` block?  Does it still prevent tab? (I don't have ffox installed so can't try myself)

Comment: @JosefP. I have commented it. But facing same Issue.